# How can escaped strings such as '\\n' be converted to their unescaped ('\n') character counterparts in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Apologies if my terminology is inverted. I am writing a parser in javascript which must be able to consume escape sequences correctly. A string in the text being parsed may include `'\\n'`, which the parser must understand as `'\n'`. Is it possible to do this without just hardcoding in all anticipated escape sequences?

In other words, is there a function `unescape` such that:

```
unescape('\\n') === '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is adding double quotes before and after and then call

```
JSON.parse(x);
```

this will handle all valid escape sequences for you

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse` can do it for `"\\n"`, but no in general there is no such function that will parse string escape sequences according to [the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-literals-string-literals). It's relatively easy to write one yourself, though.